# Setting a range for ports for a client side connection in c

Tags: c, tcp, proxy, ports

I am trying to write a TCP proxy in c. The server only works with non-ephemeral ports. The proxy is trying to mount a file-system. So when I call the mount command by-passing the proxy it chooses an appropriate port and it connects. But when I try to connect via the proxy an appropriate port is selected for the connection between the client and the proxy, but the proxy uses an ephemeral port when it connects to the server.

I have read that it is not wise to specify a port, so I am looking to define a range of ports for it to choose from. Is this possible?

Any advice and help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to bind to a reserved port prior to running the connect to the server.

use bindresvport(3) with the server socket.